# Extend WordPress search to custom field

Tags: wordpress

I would like to extend the WordPress search query_var to my custom field for custom post type. I have two custom fields, one for weekday (that works) and other for course-text. The search query_var 's' should search also in this course-text field. I have implemented:

```
function my_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search && is_post_type_archive( 'course' ) ) {
        if (!empty($query->query_vars['weekday'][0])){
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array (
                     'key' => 'course_weekday',
                     'value' => $query->query_vars['weekday'][0],
                     'compare' => '='
                )
           ));
        }
        if (!empty($query->query_vars['s'])){
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array (
                     'key' => 'course_text',
                     'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
                     'compare' => 'LIKE'
                ),
           ));
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');
```

The second one should append the 's' query_var to search innside course_text meta field.

UPDATE: I have changed pre_get_posts to

```
function my_search_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_search && is_post_type_archive( 'course' ) ) {
        if (!empty($query->query_vars['weekday'][0])){
            $query->set('meta_query', array(
                array (
                     'key' => 'course_weekday',
                     'value' => $query->query_vars['weekday'][0],
                     'compare' => '='
                )
           ));
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query');
```

Then I have added this to archive-course.php (where is my search form):

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;
    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, 
        array( 
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array (
                'key' => 'course_text',
                'value' => get_query_var('s'),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )

        ) );
    query_posts( $args );
?>
```

In this way it works. Now WP search in Custom-Post title OR in course_text by the query_var 's'.

UPDATE 2: Nope sorry, solution 2 does not working too. I had some wrong data in my first testings.

Comment: There's a typo in line 1 - `$quer` should be `$query`

Comment: It's just on my example code above, on the correct code it is `$query`. I have corrected above. But I think I have found the bug: When 's' is in Title AND in  course_text, WP found a result. So I have added a 'relation' to above code. But no effect. It seems there is bug in WordPress, I found this ticket: [link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30982). But no idea how I can fix to my problem...

Comment: Found this hint [https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query). So I have tried to do the meta_query in query_posts on the archive-posttype.php instead of pre_get_posts, and so it works.

Comment: My final conclusion: there is no way to do this. (Instead of changing directly the SQL code).